# antlr4.7 how to parse a duration spec like "P3M2D" for parts

Tags: antlr4

I am stuck trying to parse an ISO 8601 duation string (e.g. "P3M2D"). Note that this does not allow embedded spaces. I am using `antlr4.7`.

When I tried using a lexer rule

```
ISO8601_INTERVAL
    :   'P' ( y=NUMBER_INT 'Y' )? ( m=NUMBER_INT 'M' )? ( d=NUMBER_INT 'D' )?
    |   'T' etc
    ;
```

I get a compile time warning like *"labels in lexer rules are not supported in ANTLR 4; actions cannot reference elements of lexical rules but you can use getText() to get the entire text matched for the rule"*.
I would like to avoid this manual parsing.

When I tried using a parser rule

```
iso8601_INTERVAL
    :   'P' ( y=NUMBER_INT 'Y' )? ( m=NUMBER_INT 'M' )? ( d=NUMBER_INT 'D' )?
    |   'T' etc
    ;
```

I get an error like *"line 8:39 mismatched input 'P2D' expecting {'P'..."*
Is it because the lexer is expecting tokens to be separated by WS? If yes, how to temporarily suspend that?

What's the right way to having antlr4 parse out the parts of the duration input? I am rather new to antlr or compilers.

Comment: You should always include your full grammar or at least a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the input that threw you the given error message.

Comment: When I separated out an MCVE I realized that the issue is indeed elsewhere - the letters "P3M2D" are being parsed as an "ID" token. Thanks for the reminder!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ANTLR doesn't expect lexer tokens to be separated by whitespace.

From what you provided in your question the following grammar should do the job:

```
specs:
    iso*
;
iso:
    P (y=INT Y)? (m=INT M)? (d=INT D)?
;

P: 'P' ;
Y: 'Y' ;
M: 'M' ;
D: 'D' ;
INT: [0-9] ;
```

As you can see I didn't really change anything in your grammar. That is because I suspect that the error lays somewhere else in your grammar but as you haven't provided the whole grammar, the only thing I can give you is this small but (hopefully) working stand-alone grammar.